# Нужно сделать чтобы 2 игрока играли по очередности

Tags: javascript

Я написал код загадки по определению числа от 0 до 100 в Javascript.

```js
var answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 102-1);
var user = "User1"
while (true) {
 var userAnswer = prompt(user + " Игрок \n Угадайте число от 0 до 100. Для выхода введите 'q'", '');
 if (userAnswer == "q") // Если игрок ввёл "q"
{
break; // Прерываем цикл
} else // Иначе
userAnswer = parseInt(userAnswer); // Приводим введённое значение к целому числу
if (userAnswer > answer) { // Если число больше
  alert(user + " Игрок \n Ваше число больше загаданного"); // Выводим алерт
} else if (userAnswer < answer) { // Если число меньше
   alert(user + " Игрок \n Ваше число меньше загаданного"); // Выводим алерт
} else if (userAnswer == answer) { // Если угадали число
  alert(user + " Игрок \n Вы угадали! Было загадано число: " + answer); // Выводим победный алерт
  break; // Прерываем цикл
} else if (userAnswer != "q") { // Если пользователь ничего не ввёл или ввёл не число
  alert(user + " Игрок \n Необходимо ввести число"); // Выводим алерт
}

user = (user == "User1") ? "User2" : "User1";
}
```

У меня такая проблема:

- не удаётся завершить игру при правильном ответе;
- не удаётся завершить игру при введении ответа "`q`"

Comment: А зачем Вы повторно определяете переменную _user_ внутри цикла?

Comment: А чё ему "вроде" не работать? синтаксически-то всё верно. Но работает же не так, как надо? Поставьте алерты до и после _var user = (user === "User1") ? "User2" : "User1";_ с выводом значения переменной user...

Comment: Добавляйте переключение пользователей в конце цикла. А то получается что с самого начала ходит второй игрок, хотя вводит первый. Да и === тут ни к чему.

Comment: } else if (userAnswer != "q") { в конце бессмысленно. Во-первых, мы делаем break при первой проверке на q. Во-вторых приводим к int в parseInt

Comment: И да, уберите var user в цикле. сделайте в конце цикла: user = user == 'User1' ? 'User2' : 'User1';

Comment: Авазбек, прошу Вас прочитать мой комментарий по этой ссылке: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608812/

Comment: Я прочитал ваш комментарий и дискуссию по этой теме. Впредь буду осторожен с редактированием.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
 var answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 102-1);
var user = "User1"
while (true) {
  var userAnswer = prompt(user + " Игрок \n Угадайте число от 0 до 100. Для выхода введите 'q'", '');
  if (userAnswer == "q") // Если игрок ввёл "q"
  {
    break; // Прерываем цикл
  } else // Иначе
    userAnswer = parseInt(userAnswer); // Приводим введённое значение к целому числу
  if (userAnswer > answer) { // Если число больше
    alert(user + " Игрок \n Ваше число больше загаданного"); // Выводим алерт
  } else if (userAnswer < answer) { // Если число меньше
    alert(user + " Игрок \n Ваше число меньше загаданного"); // Выводим алерт
  } else if (userAnswer == answer) { // Если угадали число
    alert(user + " Игрок \n Вы угадали! Было загадано число: " + answer); // Выводим победный алерт
    break; // Прерываем цикл
  } else if (userAnswer != "q") { // Если пользователь ничего не ввёл или ввёл не число
    alert(user + " Игрок \n Необходимо ввести число"); // Выводим алерт
  }
  
    user = (user == "User1") ? "User2" : "User1";
}
```

Comment: Нажмите "выполнить код " и введите q. Как вы проверяете?..

Comment: Если user = (user == "User1") ? "User2" : "User1"; ставить в конце цикла, то переключение игроков не работает. Посмотрите в моем сообщении я его исправил. Таким образом сейчас у меня работает переключение игроков, а цикл не останавливается...

Comment: Потому что вы пишете var user = . А надо просто user =. Смотрите мой код внимательно. И всё там работает. Ещё раз повторю, нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" под вашим и моим сообщением. Ваш даже не запускается. В моём и пользователи переключаются и q работает. Проверяйте свой код.